# Can't get Autokey to work. I haven't been able to enter an abbreviation. Also, doesn't show icon after restart. Thanks

Tags: 22.04, autokey

just installed Ubuntu 22.04 on HP laptop.  Good bye Billy.
Installed Autokey for Gnome. Has all the right stuff as shown by the reviewers and explainers.  I can make entries in all appropriate fields, but can't get abbreviation accepted, which means Autokey is worthless to me.
What am I missing?

Also, why doesn't Autokey autostart??

Comment: 22.04 defaults to Wayland. Did you change to an X session at login?

Comment: Despite dancing on the fringes for 10+ years, this my first headfirst dive.  What's wayland and xsession?  I'm really trying to keep it simple and Autokey looked like Windows textr

Comment: Wayland and X are two alternative "display managers." They run the graphical environment. Try this: Log out. Log back in. At the password screen, look for a gear icon. Select an X session from that icon instead of the default (Wayland) session. Then try autokey again.

Comment: Not seeing this.  Are you referring to something in the boot menu?

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunatelly, keyboard automation tools do not work on Wayland, the new display driver used by Ubuntu 22.04. You need to log in on an Xorg session for making this work.

1. Log out using the "logout" option in the system menu (when you click on the combined wifi/speaker/battery icon in the top right.
2. In the login screen, select your username so you could type your password
3. Before typing your password, click the cog wheel on the bottom right, then select "Ubuntu on Xorg". Now enter your password and log in.

[image]

Comment: You aren't  vanadium, you are golden.

Comment: You aren't  vanadium, you are golden.  I've worked with computers for over 50 years,  It seems AskUbuntu is the reference of choice for obscure knowledge and patience.  Thank you.  Noob out.

Comment: I agree, you possess power, one couldn't imagine. Bowing to you 