# Enable autokey shortcuts on terminal on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: keyboard, shortcuts, autokey

I just updated to Ubuntu 22.04 and I've encountered a problem with autokey: the shortcuts don't seem to work on the terminal. They work elsewhere, and it was working on 20.04 but now not anymore. I tried looking on the terminal and autokey preferences but couldn't find something that might enable this.

All help is greatly appreciated

Edit: no worries, it seems the answer is vanadium's answer to this question

[Can't get Autokey to work. I haven't been able to enter an abbreviation. Also, doesn't show icon after restart. Thanks](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1412258/cant-get-autokey-to-work-i-havent-been-able-to-enter-an-abbreviation-also-d)

Comment: it seems the answer is vanadium's answer to this post: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1412258/cant-get-autokey-to-work-i-havent-been-able-to-enter-an-abbreviation-also-d

Comment: @vanadium yes! I'd actually found your answer to that question a bit after posting mine, it worked like a charm. thank you!