# What is the purpose of these linux commands and how does it work?.Is it a temporary or permanent solution?

Tags: drivers, apt, xorg, wacom

I recently installed ubundu 22.04 ,after i reboot the system my keybord was not working and by surfing on internet i found out about these commands and after using these commands on terminal my keyboard start working again but on the third day it got back to starting stage (not working) ie, after multiple booting either i have done something wrong or these linux command are temporary solution for input drivers.

`sudo apt install xserver-xorg-input-all`

`sudo apt install xserver-xorg-input-libinput`

`sudo apt install xserver-xorg-input-wacom`

Comment: Generally, `sudo apt install program-package` provides a permanent solution, and when there will be upgrades available (found by `sudo apt update`), they will be used by `sudo apt upgrade` or (preferred by me) `sudo apt full-upgrade`. It is possible that some upgrade caused your problem, it is difficult to know without more details about your system, there could also be some other cause.

Answer (score 2):

These commands install input drivers for the Xorg display server, which actually are normally already installed in a default Ubuntu installation.

You are likely using Wayland, however, because that is the default display server in Ubuntu 22.04.

There might be issues with Wayland and some specific hardware. You therefore may check whether running Xorg works better for you. See here for instructions on how to [switch to an Xorg session](https://askubuntu.com/a/1412418/558158).

Comment: Thank you for this information, may the force be with you!

Comment: Please "accept" this answer if it answered your question. Click the checkmark next to the question. This shows other users that a useful answer can be found here.