# How to configure focus-follows-mouse

Tags: gnome, upgrade, mouse, window, focus

Upgraded from Ubuntu 20.04 to 22.04 yesterday. I like windows to gain focus when the mouse is over the window (focus on hover) and remain there even if your pointer is moved to the desktop. I'm unable to do that.

I've tried setting it with Tweaks; under menu Windows there is Window Focus section, and there there are the options Click to Focus, Focus on Hover, and Secondary-Click. Focus on Hover seems to describe what I want but it is acting the same as Secondary-Click: it looses focus when I move the pointer away from the window to the desktop.

I think that Focus on Hover is the option I used when I configured 20.04. Perhaps I need to configure it differently? Any comments?

Comment: Focus on hover is the right choice, and should need no additional configuration. On my machines the window won't lose focus when the pointer enters the desktop, so I don't know why your experience is different.

Comment: @vanadium. Thank you for the clarification. Is it possible to select Xorg sessions as default? Would I miss a lot by not using Wayland?

Comment: Maybe this or other gnome extensions work for that https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/767/focus-follows-mouse/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are facing (yet another) difference between Wayland and Xorg. In Wayland, the option to keep the application focused even if the cursor already moved to the desktop does not work as such. The "sloppy" focus mode behaves identical to "mouse", i.e., where the window only keeps focus if the mouse is over it.

To regain the old behavior, you could instead [switch back to an Xorg session](https://askubuntu.com/a/1412418/558158).