# Browser windows are blank

Tags: chromium

I have a very old laptop with Ubuntu on it and a few days before I updated it to version 22.04. After I did it all the windows that my browser create are completely blank. Before that I used 20.04 version and Chromium worked properly.

- I can see all the windows below browser window, sometimes a bit glitchy.
- There is no usual window border, but it works properly - I can resize a window or close it by pushing the place where close button usually is.
- Activity manager shows that the window is present, so does the dock.

I tried different browsers (Chromium, Chrome, Opera, Firefox) and they all created blank windows. I tried rebooting, clearing cache and reinstalling the app (from Software store) but nothing helped.

When starting Chromium from the command line it shows a lot of errors responding to the fact that my laptop doesn't have any GPU. However, when starting it with "--disable-gpu" flag I see the following:

- `Gtk-message: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"` is outputted twice. I couldn't fix it myself.
- The blank window appears.
- After a few seconds `[Error:udev_watcher.cc(98)] Failed to begin udev enumeration.` appears.
- After that process doesn't stop until I press Ctrl+C or close the browser window.

Current Ubuntu version is 22.04.1, Chromium version is 105.0.5195.52 Snap.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Perhaps due to Wayland. Try switching to an Xorg session and see if the issue is gone: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1412258/cant-get-autokey-to-work-i-havent-been-able-to-enter-an-abbreviation-also-d/1412418#1412418

Comment: @vanadium you are a true hero. I couldn't continue my work for several days and now I am saved. Thank you very much!!!