# Can't use xprop on Firefox

Tags: firefox, xprop

i've updated my System to Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS, which runs pretty good so far. But Firefox behaves weird, i can't use `xprop | grep WM_CLASS` on Firefox Windows. None of the `xprop` commands are working, the cursor also don't turn to a cross, when i hover a Firefox Window. It works like expected for Chrome, Opera or Thunderbird Windows, but not for Firefox.

I had the issue with the pre-installed snap Version from Firefox, so i uninstalled it and installed Firefox just as a package, but the issue remains. I use `[xdotool][1]` to reload Browsers via Command, and Firefox Windows are not even recognized at all.

Firefox 105.0.2

---

Problem solved. I had another cursor issue before and ended up with

`MOZ_ENABLE_WAYLAND=1`

in `/etc/environment`

This caused the problem with `xprop` and `xdotool`. Chrome, Opera and all the other stuff are running from snap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Ubuntu system now is running on the new windowing system Wayland instead of the traditional system Xorg. This is fundamentally different, and many of the "good old" tools that interact with Xorg do not work on Wayland.

Some applications that do not support Wayland run on Xorg through an interface laye, xwayland. These tools will continue to work for these applications.

The Snap version of Firefox actually runs on xwayland for me. So for the default version, the tools would work. Firefox installed from third party sources via the APT system natively run on Wayland, so the tools do not work.

You can tell whether an application runs on xwayland if it appears in the output of `wmctrl -l` in a Wayland session.

So here is why you cannot use `xprop`.

If these tools are important in your workflow, you still can [run Ubuntu on Xorg](https://askubuntu.com/a/1412418/558158) instead as of old (I personally do). You will loose touchpad functionality, and in particular one-to-one mouse gestures. Wayland supports different scaling factors when using different monitors, Xorg does not. In some cases, Wayland animations may be noticeably more smooth than on Xorg. In the end, you must make the balance and choose for yourself what you prefer to use.

Comment: It was really just a snap thing, but also mixed with Wayland. I had former issues with the cursor in Firefox and ended up with this Setting

`MOZ_ENABLE_WAYLAND=1`

in `/etc/environment`

If it's setted, Firefox don't appear in `wmctrl -l` or `xprop`. Great, i can keep my Workflow and Wayland, thx :)

Answer (score 0):

When you upgraded your system to Ubuntu 22.04 do you recall you got a message saying that Firefox was a SNAP now? If you want to use the features you asked about you need to remove the snap version and install the apt version.

The following commands should do this for you.

sudo snap remove firefox

sudo apt-get install --reinstall firefox

Comment: I already removed the Snap Version and installed Firefox via apt, but the issue remains. I can't pick open Firefox windows using `xprop`, the Windows containing Firefox instances are somehow invisible for `xprop`

Comment: Sounds like you are still using the snap version.

Comment: My Profile-Directory is now in `/home/me/.mozilla/firefox/...default-release`. It was in a snap directory, but i uninstalled and removed it completely and used apt to reinstall Firefox. Does `xprop` works on your System on Firefox?

Comment: Not related to snap. Just reinstalling firefox will not result in a deb version. Wrong info here.

Comment: It was a mix of snap and wayland. I had

`MOZ_ENABLE_WAYLAND=1`

in `/etc/environment`

That caused the problem.