# Keyboard Shortcuts and "Find Files on Desktop"

Tags: keyboard, 22.04

I am trying to control OBS using keyboard shortcuts. However, whatever keys I map, when I press them the "Find files on desktop" window pops up.

I looked at the Gnome extensions, and the only way I could suppress this behaviour was to disable the dock.

Does anyone know another way to prevent this pop-up from appearing?

Ubuntu 22.04

Answer (score 0):

You are on Wayland. One of the current issues with Wayland is that applications cannot define global keyboard shortcuts, i.e., keyboard shortcuts of the application that are active over the entire desktop.

This does not answer your question "Does anyone know another way to prevent this pop-up from appearing?", but it tells you why the OBS shortcut keys do not work. Still, thank you for pointing out your finding that this annoying feature appears to be provided by the Ubuntu dock.

For now, a practical workaround is to [switch to an Xorg session](https://askubuntu.com/a/1412418/558158) (at least when you need to record).