# Ubuntu 22.04 freezes

Tags: 22.04, freeze, 22.10

I started using Linux for the first time. I installed Ubuntu 22.10, but when i use it for few minutes. The OS freezes completely. Nothing response not even mouse cursor. I have to force restart my laptop. Yesterday, I was transferring my files to my Mobile phone via cable and as soon as I start transferring file, the os freezes and becomes unresponsive. I thought it might be issue with 22.10 so I installed 22.04. but still the issue remains the same. I'm using dell latitude 7480 core i7-7th gen with 8GB RAM.

Comment: Look for errors in `journalctl` output.

Comment: Can you try switching to an Xorg session as explained here: https://askubuntu.com/a/1412418/558158 This may solve the issues.